# how to cache Background subtraction data for later usage?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, background-subtraction

background subtraction methods in `OpenCV` usually take a while to get the foreground correct. is there any way to cache data of these methods and use them later? (preferred in `Python`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe so. The [cv::BackgroundSubtractor](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/df6/classcv_1_1BackgroundSubtractor.html) derives from cv::Algorithm, which supports `read()`, `save()`, and `write()`. specific BackgroundSubtractor subclasses should have implemented those methods.

These methods should be exposed in the Python API; the docs mention Python signatures.